# File input with FAB

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic4, floating-action-button, html-input

I am using **@ionic-react**. It is very easy to use.

What I wonder is how to make use of html input type file with a [IonButton](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button) or [IonFabButton](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab-button) to have the looks of that Ionic element instead of html input type file element?

According to docs the [IonInput](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input)  component is for text like input types.

> It is meant for text  `type`  inputs only, such as  `"text"` ,  `"password"` ,  `"email"` ,  `"number"` ,  `"search"` ,  `"tel"` , and  `"url"` . It supports all standard text input events including keyup, keydown, keypress, and more.

Demonstrating some code I have tried:

```
     <IonFab slot="fixed" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end">

        <IonFabButton>
            <IonIcon name="add" />
        </IonFabButton>

        <IonFabList side="top">

            <IonFabButton color="primary">
                <IonIcon name="document" />
                <input type="file" onChange={appendScene} hidden style={{opacity: 0, width: "1px", height: "1px"}}/>
                <IonInput readonly></IonInput>
            </IonFabButton>

            <IonFabButton color="secondary">
                <IonIcon name="folder" />
            </IonFabButton>

        </IonFabList>

      </IonFab>
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a "hidden" input of type file (hidden = opacity being 0 and width and height being 1px) and add a visible input being this input `readonly` and handle what to do in the component code...

Comment: I have tried this added code. But I think I need more leads on handling.